# Blender Crashes after a few Renders from a Batch Script

Tags: rendering, command-line, windows

On Windows 7 I am rendering a series of animations from Blender in a batch script that looks like this:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b "E:\Project.blend" -S Scene1 -o "E:\exports\Fredericksburg1\Fredericksburg1_" -F JPEG -s 001 -e 435 -a
call "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b "E:\Project.blend" -S Scene2 -o "E:\exports\Fredericksburg2\Fredericksburg2_" -F JPEG -s 001 -e 480 -a
call "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b "E:\Project.blend" -S Scene3 -o "E:\exports\Fredericksburg3\Fredericksburg3_" -F JPEG -s 001 -e 180 -a
```

My problem is that after rendering one or two files, the rest of the Blender instances crash immediately after reading the preferences. The crash file just has this:

```
# Blender 2.69 (sub 0), Revision: 60995
```

It is not related to which project I use, usually only the first one or two render. 
I have tried a few things, making sure the computer didn't go to sleep or even the screen go blank, play around with the `.bat` file, but I haven't been able to get anything to consistently work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change from a batch script to a python script. You can call the python script on startup by adding a parameter to the call like so:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b "E:\Project.blend" -P pythonScript.py
```

the python script would look somewhat like this:

pythonScript.py:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

renderInformation = {
    'Scene1': (r'E:\exports\Fredericksburg1\Fredericksburg1_', [1, 435], 'JPEG'),
    'Scene2': (r'E:\exports\Fredericksburg2\Fredericksburg2_', [1, 480], 'JPEG'),
    'Scene3': (r'E:\exports\Fredericksburg3\Fredericksburg3_', [1, 180], 'JPEG'),}
# you can use any slash and just copy-paste the path from the explorer
# as long as it doesn't end with a "\'"

@persistant
def callbackFunc(context=None):
    try:
        sceneIdent, info = renderInformation.popitem() # get the next scene to render
        scene = bpy.data.scenes[sceneIdent] # get the actual scene
        bpy.context.screen.scene = scene # set the scene
        (scene.render.filepath,
         (scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end),
         scene.render.image_settings.file_format) = info # extract information
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True) # render as animation
    except:
        pass # then the list is exhausted and we can end the process

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if callbackFunc not in bpy.app.handlers.render_complete:
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(callbackFunc) # we register a callback after each render
    callbackFunc() # and call it ourselves at first
```

This just keeps blender down to one instance and might be worth considering anyways if you want to get deeper into the action, with more scenes to render etc. A batch script for that seems quite irrational, idk :)

I hope this fixes the problem for you, if not, then you might consider taking a look at your CPU-loading, maybe your scenes are just too big :? I don't think so since two render good but you never know. Tell me if there is anything you're interested about or if the proposed "solution" doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm nearly certain it's not a CPU issue, the scenes are very simple and it's a powerful computer.

Comment: When I run with the python script, I get the error, `NameError: name 'callbackFunc' is not defined'`. When I move the definition of the function up, I get the error `callbackFunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` Any idea what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: I misinterpreted the argument :) you get the current scene passed. As you are not interested in that you can call it with None in "__main__"

Comment: Thanks for that. Now when I run it goes into `callbackFunc`, sets the parameters correctly, but does not actually render.

Comment: Any chance to make progress?

Comment: Possible workaround: you paste the above script into a texteditor after blender startup and run it once. This is no perfect and automated solution but better than nothing, right? *nervous laugh

Comment: Worked a bit on the script and I think this solution should work without you doing anything at all!